# TypeORM SQL SubQuery

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, typeorm

I want to retrieve a list of maintenances, distincted by ids and sorted by date.

Basically, I'm trying to translate this SQL query (under PostgreSQL) :

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT m.id, * 
  FROM maintenances AS m 
  LEFT JOIN maintenance_items AS mi ON mi.maintenance_id = m.id 
  LEFT JOIN maintenance_types AS mt ON mi.type = mt.id 
  WHERE bike_id = '152cd134-c868-4a9e-ad49-691569f5786d'
) AS foo 
ORDER BY foo.m_date;
```

as a TypeORM query. I tried this :

```
DbConnection.manager
    .createQueryBuilder<Maintenance>(Maintenance, 'maintenances')
    .select('*')
    .from(qb => qb.subQuery()
      .select('*')
      .from(Maintenance, 'maintenances')
      .where('maintenances.bikeID = :id', { id: id })
      .leftJoinAndSelect('maintenances.items', 'maintenance_items')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('maintenance_items.type', 'maintenance_types')
      .distinctOn(['maintenances.id']), 'foo')
    .orderBy('foo.m_date', 'DESC')
```

And I'm getting this error : Cannot get entity metadata for the given alias "foo". Cannot figure out why.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your TypeOrm query is selecting from Maintenance table two times, once with `createQueryBuilder<Maintenance>().Select('*')`, and again in `subQuery()`.

Much simpler is to use `manager.query(sql)` instead of `manager.createQueryBuilder()`.

Example:

```
let bike_id = '152cd134-c868-4a9e-ad49-691569f5786d';

const sql = `SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT m.id, * 
  FROM maintenances AS m 
  LEFT JOIN maintenance_items AS mi ON mi.maintenance_id = m.id 
  LEFT JOIN maintenance_types AS mt ON mi.type = mt.id 
  WHERE bike_id = $1
) AS foo 
ORDER BY foo.m_date`;

let result = await DbConnection.manager.query(sql, [bike_id]);

console.log(result);
```

Points to note:

- In TypeScript or JavaScript, use backticks `` `sql` `` to delimit the multiline-sql string
- For PostgreSQL, if any column name in your raw SQL contains any uppercase characters, you need to enclose it in double-quotes
- When using `manager.query`, the query parameters have to use syntax specific for the DBMS

| DBMS | Parameter syntax |
| --- | --- |
| PostgreSQL | $1, $2 |
| MySQL / MariaDB | ?, ? ... |
| SQLite | ?, ? ... |
| Microsoft SQL Server | @0, @1 ... |

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but is there a way to use TypeORM entities here, as createQueryBuilder alredy does ? ? As it returns a raw result, I need to manually rename the output fields "select XXX as YYY" etc.... and I have a lot of fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getrawOne() to retrieve data. This will not show error.